# "Нашли(,) из-за чего поссориться" -- запятая

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, запятые, предлоги

Нужна ли запятая в указанном месте?

> Нашли(,) из-за чего поссориться

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Запятая не нужна. См. у [**Розенталя:**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=146#pp146)

> **§ 41. Цельные по смыслу выражения**
>
> Цельные по смыслу выражения не отделяются и не выделяются запятыми.
>
> <…>
>
> 7. Внутри выражений типа ***есть чем заняться, есть над чем поработать, было о чём подумать, найду куда обратиться, не нахожу что
>      сказать, осталось на что жить***, состоящих из глагола ***быть***, или
>      ***найти (найтись)***, или ***остаться*** и вопросительно-относительного местоимения либо наречия (***кто, что,
>      где, куда, когда*** и т. д.) **и неопределенной формы другого глагола,
>      запятая не ставится**: *Тебе есть в мире что забыть* (Л.); *Бранить
>      есть кому, кормить — некому* (Даль); *Есть чему и нравиться* (Пис); *И
>      нашу интеллигенцию есть за что любить, есть за что уважать* (М. Г.);
>      *Есть над чем задуматься; **Нашли чем удивить**; Не нашёлся что сказать; У нас будет чем козырнуть; Нашла где модничать; Есть когда с
>      тобой болтать!; Было отчего приуныть; Друзьям есть о чём поговорить;
>      Ребятам было где проводить свободное время; Нам было в чём упрекнуть
>      его.*